# Extending Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm using Timber for the first time, and I find that it is hard to convert my pure PHP thinking to this templating model.

What I'm confused about at the moment is using a date which is an input field, not the post date.

So I've got a repeater field from ACF. It has three sub-fields: `release_date`, `document_file`, and `document_title`. My release date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

As you might have guessed, this repeater field is output as a list of PDFs.

So far so good, but then I want some advanced functionality - namely, to have the PDFs display by release_date by default. I also want to be able to filter by the year, i.e. - if you click "2015", it would only show the documents from that year.

I know exactly how I would do this in straight WordPress, but I'm pretty confused making it on Timber. I've been trying to do it using a custom filter, but I have felt what I actually want is a custom class?

In addition, when I installed Timber it didn't come with the starter theme, so I did a search and downloaded one from GitHub. I've got a feeling this is a legacy version though, because the file structure and syntax doesn't seem to match the documentation.

Downloaded from here: https://github.com/timber/starter-theme

But for example this code in the starter theme functions.php:

```
function add_to_twig( $twig ) {
    /* this is where you can add your own functions to twig */
    $twig->addExtension( new Twig_Extension_StringLoader() );
    $twig->addFilter('split_date', new Twig_SimpleFilter('split_date', array($this, 'split_date')));
    return $twig;
}
```

Doesn't quite match the syntax in https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/Extending-Timber under "Adding to Twig".

Comment: The syntax for adding the `filter` is a bit different but still correct. Using `array($this, 'split_date`)` is equal telling to `twig`: Add a new filter `split_date` and allocate it the function based in `$this` class. The example in the documentation is using global functions instead of class methods

Comment: OK, cool, so that's not deprecated. Is it a reasonable way of doing what I'm trying to achieve, though? I want to be able to split the date (hence `split_date`) and use day, year and month separately.

Comment: If your releasedate is a valid date string i'd go with : `<a href="route/to/file?year={{ release_date | date('Y') }}">{{ release_date | date('Y-m-d') }}</a>`

Comment: Have just come to this discovery myself thanks to looking at `footer.twig` for the first time. That is exactly what I'm looking for, cheers. It is perfectly nice and simple, though I'm still a little confused by the documentation. I didn't see that syntax in the examples anywhere.

Comment: You can see the different methods of adding filters to twig in their document over [here](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters)

Comment: So actually it turns out I'm still confused. I think I'm having difficulty conceptualising MVC correctly. Imagine in pure PHP I had something like `<a href="page.php?varName=value">`. How could I do something similar with Timber? Can I pass the query string to twig and use a filter? Or should I still be passing the query string to PHP, and outputting only what I need before displaying with twig?

Comment: Every data modification should happen in the controller. Always start from the point "Don't trust user input", this means you have to validate and/or modify the user input. The  controller is the place where this happens. In your template you just output data, either with or without looping the data or wrapping it around conditions

Comment: OK thanks.... this is my first time using MVC and it's confusing to grasp straight up. I think I've got it and then bam! confusion again :P

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few helper functions to make it easy for me to extend timber.

```
function add_context_var( $key, $var ) {
    add_filter( 'timber_context', function ( $context ) use ( $key, $var ) {
        $context[ $key ] = $var;

        return $context;
    } );
}

function add_context_func( $key, $callback ) {
    add_filter( 'timber/twig', function ( $twig ) use ( $key, $callback ) {
        $twig->addFunction( new \Twig_SimpleFunction( $key, $callback ) );

        return $twig;
    } );
}

function add_to_context( $key, $val ) {
    if ( is_callable( $val ) ) {
        add_context_func( $key, $val );
    } else {
        add_context_var( $key, $val );
    }
}

function add_to_context_filter( $key, $callback ) {
    add_filter( 'get_twig', function ( $twig ) use ( $key, $callback ) {
        $twig->addExtension( new Twig_Extension_StringLoader() );
        $twig->addFilter( new Twig_SimpleFilter( $key, $callback ) );

        return $twig;
    } );
}

//php file
add_to_context("blue", "this key is blue")
add_to_context("red", function($extra = ""){
  return "this key is red and it has $extra";
})
add_to_context_filter( "relative_link", function ( $content ) {
    return str_replace( "http://", "//", $content );;
} );

//twig file
color: {{ blue }}
color: {{ red("a function parameter") }}
github: {{ "http://github.com/"|relative_link }}

//output html
color: this key is blue
color: this key is red and it has function parameter
github: //github.com/
```